# Confused w/ syntactic assignment of classes in html

Tags: html, css, class, button, positioning

So, I'm having trouble understanding the difference between commas to separate classes and the absence of them. Also, I am using 'Skeleton' style sheets for the grid system. Here's an example:

```
<div id="header_buttons" class="eleven columns, header_buttons">
  <button type="button"><a href="#">Github</a></button>
</div>
```

And for 'header_buttons':

```
.header_buttons {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

With the commas, I get my intended result:[image]

But without them, I get this instead:
[image]

I know the basis of having multiple classes is to not use commas. But in my case, if I take them out, why do I not get my intended result?

Comment: @Michael Coker: Why would having a comma at the end of "columns" invalidate the "eleven" class?

Comment: @BoltClock oops I meant `column` instead of `eleven`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skeleton adds `.column:first-child { margin-left: 0; }`, so that rule will have higher specificity than `.header_buttons { margin-left: 180px; }`.

Without the comma in your markup, `.column:first-child { margin-left: 0; }` is applied via skeleton and overwrites `.header_buttons { margin-left: 180px; }`

When you add the comma there, that breaks skeleton's `.column` class so that rule no longer applies, and the rule you specified for `.header_buttons` applies.

You can see it here

```css
.header_buttons {
  margin-left: 180px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="header_buttons" class="eleven columns header_buttons">
  <button type="button"><a href="#">Github</a></button>
</div>

<div id="header_buttons" class="eleven columns, header_buttons">
  <button type="button"><a href="#">Github</a></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, so Skeleton *doesn't* rely on commas and this was just experimentation on part of the asker?

Comment: @BoltClock yessir. that would be wonky if skeleton actually used commas in their class names! You'd have to escape that in the stylesheet. That would be a complicated mess :)

Comment: Ahhh. Well I've seen grid systems and other frameworks doing really crazy things with the class attribute, so that idea wasn't all that far-fetched to me. Guess I assumed wrong this time :)